# How to send parameters to Sever(Cloud Functions) using XmlHttpRequest for website

Tags: javascript, node.js, xmlhttprequest, bootstrap-4

I am trying to call My server using XMLHttpRequest. Currently, I am running my website in localhost. So I wrote the statements like this :

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var url = "https://us-central1-deyapay-192704.cloudfunctions.net/Add"; 
  var params1 = {
  "AuthID": userid,
  "Amount":amt};
  var params = JSON.stringify(params1);
  console.log(amt);
  console.log(userid);
  xhttp.open("POST", url, true);
  xhttp.setRequestHeader( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  //xhttp.withCredentials = false;
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

  xhttp.onload = function() {
    var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
     console.log(data);
  }
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
    if(xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
        alert(xhttp.responseText);
    }
}
xhttp.send(
    params
  );
```

So whenever I run that HTML file then I got these errors like "`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()"` and `"Failed to load https://us-central1-deyapay-192704.cloudfunctions.net/Add: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:5000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500."`  and it shows error at Sending Parameters to sever. The screenshot is :
[image]

[image]
At the server, I got the error like  "Argument "documentPath" is not a valid ResourcePath. The path must be a non-empty string." and The values passing from XMLHttpRequest to sever is null. At sever side it prints NAN.
How to solve that error?

Comment: check in your network tab of your request. is there the headers of Access-Control-Allow-Origin ?

Comment: No. I didn't observe any headers related   to Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Comment: that's mean your xhttp.setRequestHeader( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*') is not set up properly. you need to setup the header to allow the browser to access server outside this self domain (localhost)

Comment: ok.  i will try it

Comment: @punk73 I updated my question I put a screenshot of network tab. once look into that.

Comment: https://us-central1-deyapay-192704.cloudfunctions.net/Add --> is it your server ?? and you that wrote the code ?? if it yes, you need to setup the server to allow CORS on options and another http method. 

please refer : https://enable-cors.org/

Comment: Yes, it is server address https://us-central1-deyapay-192704.cloudfunctions.net/Add. I used the cloud functions as sever. And I wrote the server code in node.js.

Comment: I add these lines in my code res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*")
  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST'). But same error is occured.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170742/discussion-between-vijju-and-punk73).

Comment: don't forget to add options to CORS. since before you can allow another http method, you always send the options first.

Comment: How to add options to CORS

Comment: asuming you set the method right, res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS')

Comment: I am getting the same error.

Comment: I am getting the error at xhttp.send(params);